# why alignas(64) not aligned with 64

Tags: c++, alignas

why alignas(64) not aligned with 64? for example:

```cpp
struct alignas(32) st32
{
    float a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint64_t c;
};

struct alignas(64) st64
{
    float a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint64_t c;
};

int main()
{
    st32 x;
    st64 y;

    std::cout
        << "alignof(st32) = " << alignof(st32) << '\n'
        << "alignof(st64) = " << alignof(st64) << '\n'
        << "&st32 a: " << &x.a << '\n'
        << "&st32 b: " << &x.b << '\n'
        << "&st32 c: " << &x.c << '\n'
        << "&st64 a: " << &y.a << '\n'
        << "&st64 b: " << &y.b << '\n'
        << "&st64 c: " << &y.c << '\n'; 
}
```

The results is

```
alignof(st32) = 32
alignof(st64) = 64
&st32 a: 0x7ffc59fc9660
&st32 b: 0x7ffc59fc9664
&st32 c: 0x7ffc59fc9668
&st64 a: 0x7ffc59fc9680
&st64 b: 0x7ffc59fc9684
&st64 c: 0x7ffc59fc9688
```

why `&st64 b: 0x7ffc59fc9684` is not `0x7ffc59fc9688`, beacause the address need to 64bits aligned, we should leave `0x7ffc59fc9684-0x7ffc59fc9688` blank, and start next data at `0x7ffc59fc9688`.

Comment: You've aligned the struct, not the field `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why &st64 b: 0x7ffc59fc9684 is not 0x7ffc59fc9688

Aligning a structure does not affect the alignment of the sub objects of the structure. The address of the enclosing structure is 64 byte aligned, and `b` is the second member after a 4 byte sized `a`, so it's reasonable to expect `b` to not be 64 byte aligned.

> if alignas don't align the sub object, then what's the point of this syntax before struct.

The point is to align the class itself. This is sometimes needed for example for SIMD instructions.

Comment: But why 32 bit align will set `uint16_t b` to 4bytes

Comment: @dahohu527 It is stored at offset of 4 bytes from the beginning of the stucture because there is a sub object of 4 bytes at offset 0 so the offset 4 is the first unused byte so far. And that 4 byte offset satisfies the aligment requirement of  `std::uint16_t` which is 2 bytes.

Comment: it's puzzle me a lot, if alignas don't align the sub object, then what's the point of this syntax before struct. So what is the best way to align the subobject?

Comment: @dahohu527 Why would you want to align a "subobject" (field) from its natural alignment?

Comment: I use `Eigen::Matrix4d` and the pcl library use `c[i] = _mm256_load_pd (tf.col (i).data ())` which tf is `Eigen::Matrix4d`, but `_mm256_load_pd ` need 256bits aligned, I'm not sure about why `Eigen::Matrix4d` is 256 aligned is ok , or the `tf.col (i).data ()` is???

Answer (score 2):

This will give you what you seem to want:

```
struct alignas(64) st64
{
    float a;
    alignas(64) uint16_t b;
    uint64_t c;
};
```

Output:

```
alignof(st32) = 32
alignof(st64) = 64
&st32 a: 0x7ffe33498ae0
&st32 b: 0x7ffe33498ae4
&st32 c: 0x7ffe33498ae8
&st64 a: 0x7ffe33498b00
&st64 b: 0x7ffe33498b40
&st64 c: 0x7ffe33498b48
```